# Solve $k=\gcd\left(n,\text{digitreverse}\left(n\right)\right)$ for positive integers $n$ that only contain the digits $1$ and $0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, gcd-and-lcm

Well, I have a positive integer $n$ that only contain the digits $1$ and $0$. Besides that I have a positive integer $k$, which must have a last digit equal to $1,3,7$ or $9$. Solve the equation below:

$$k=\gcd\left(n,\text{digitreverse}\left(n\right)\right)\tag1$$

Where $\text{digitreverse}\left(\cdot\right)$ reverses the digits of $n$.

So for example when $n=10100101$ we get $\text{digitreverse}\left(10100101\right)=10100101$.

---

**Edit:** I do not really have a way of solving this. I only found two solutions by hand (which I do not know are the only solutions possible):

1. When $k=9$, we find $n=1011111111$;
2. When $k=17$, we find $n=11111110010111111111$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @MartinR I am very sorry. I edited my question. Hints and other advice is also nice to get.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @MartinR From my number theory class.

Answer (score 1):

We call $"n"$ a good number if $n$ contains only the digits $0$ and $1$.
We will show that the following proposition is true.

[Proposition]
For any positive integer $k>1$ with $\gcd(k,10)=1$, there exist infinitely many good numbers $n$ such that $k=\gcd\left(n,\text{digitreverse}\left(n\right)\right)$.

[Proof]
Since $\gcd(k,10)=1$, there exist infinitely many positive integers $e$ such that $10^e \equiv 1\pmod{k}$.
Since $k>1$ is an odd number, we can take $s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k=2s+1$.
Set $n = -10^{se} + \sum_{i=0}^{k}10^{ie}$.
Then $m:=\text{digitreverse}\left(n\right) = -10^{(s+1)e} + \sum_{i=0}^{k}10^{ie}$.
Set $d = \gcd(m,n) = \gcd(m,n-m)$.
Since $n-m = 10^{se}(10^e-1)$ and $\gcd(d,10)=1$, we have $10^e \equiv 1\pmod{d}$.
So we have $0 \equiv n \equiv -1 + \sum_{i=0}^{k}1 = k \pmod{d}$, which implies $k \geq d$.
Since $10^e \equiv 1\pmod{k}$, we also have $n \equiv m \equiv 0 \pmod{k}$, which implies $d \geq k$.
Since $k \geq d$ and $d \geq k$, we must have $k=d$.
So we can say that $k=\gcd\left(n,\text{digitreverse}\left(n\right)\right)$.
$\blacksquare$